# How to access textarea value from one HTML form in another HTML form using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to access the the `textarea` value which is part of one form in another form, but I am not able to do so. The code has been attached as follows.

```
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
        <form action="board.php" method="POST">
        <textarea id="text_message" name="new_message" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="message" value="New Post"/>
                </form>

                <form action="board.php" method="GET">


               <?php

    echo '<table>
                <tr><td><a href="board.php?reply=12345</td></tr>
                </table>';

                if(isset($_GET['reply'])){
                $message= $_POST['new_message'];

                echo $message;
                }

        ?>
            </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Getting an error saying `Undefined index: new_message in \board.php on line 47`

Comment: Whr is your board.php file

Comment: No offense intended, but your question and your code show that you are quite the beginner. Perhaps you'd better first check out a comprehensive tutorial on PHP programming. Here, for example, you're mixing $_GET and $_POST, server code and client "code" - there's no way this is ever going to work as it is.

Comment: I assume this file is board.php and you're clicking on `board.php?reply=12345` to try to execute your code, right? But, as @Iserni hints at above, you aren't doing a post and a get. At that point, you're only doing a get request. So, your `isset` condition is true, but there's nothing in `$_POST` because you haven't submitted the form yet.

Comment: Thanks for all the help... I apologize for my poor way of posting the question. Its the first time I have ever posted something on stackoverflow... so I am kind of new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to make a field populated with an old message when replying, but where do you intend to get the new_message? Your link (a href) does not send the new_message (also, it is missing the rest of the link information). Currently it looks like `reply` and `new_message` will never be populated at the same time, as they come from different forms. Maybe you meant to have a hidden field in the first form? e.g.

```
<textarea id="text_message" name="new_message" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="reply" value="12345"/>
        <input type="submit" name="message" value="New Post"/>
        </form>
```

When you click that submit button, you would have both a reply and a new_message field (although they would both be in _POST). In short, a description of a more full desired workflow would be helpful here.